# Counting and Assigning for number of PNP devices in powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line, automation

I am trying to write a code for different conditions if the Get-pnpdevice outputs more/less than 2 devices of the same FreindlyName. Can anyone help with how to select the number of queries produced by Get-pnpdevice?

```
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName '*Generic USB*'

$env:disid = Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName '*Generic USB*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InstanceId
$NoOfDis - Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName '*Generic USB*' | Select-Object -property FriendlyName
$env:displayid
$NoOfDis

if ( (Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName '*Generic USB*') -gt 1){

"More than 1 "
}
elseif ( Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName '*Generic USB*' -eq 1){
"Equal to 1"
Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $env:disid
}

elseif( Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName '*Generic USB*' -lt 1){

"No device connected" 
}
```

For Example if Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName '*Generic USB*'  outputs like this:

```
Status     Class           FriendlyName       InstanceId                                                              
------     -----           ------------      ------------                                                               
OK         ETC      GenericUSB           SWD\PRIN...   
OK         ​ETC      GenericUSB           SWD\PRIN...
```

How can I  assign  $NoOfDis  to the number of the devices found under the FreindlyName?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the Count method.

Example:

```
If ((Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName '*Generic USB*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InstanceId).Count) -gt 1) { Write-Host "More than 1" }
```